# How to repair files from linux rescue

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

It seems that a lot of necessary system modules were uninstalled by mistake , so the original linux server doesn't function anymore and cannot be accessed through ssh or ftp. but I can access through rescue linux, is there a command to enter to make linux copy any missing module from the rescue linux to the faulty installation?

for example on Windows I can boot into windows and choose repair, which is re-install.  I can do that also from linux if I have direct access to the PC. but how to do that through ssh in linux-rescue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the rescue image is specifically compiled for the distribution/version of the installed system this is not a good idea. Its good security practice to install distributir supplied patches when they are available - and maintaining a rescue disk which is an exact copy of the current state of your system would be a nightmare. Indeed, given the complications of this approach I doubt anyone would provide a rescue image capable of this.

The right way to fix the problem would be to boot up off the rescue image and restore the missing files from your backup. But presumably you don't have a backup since you're asking the question.

So that just leaves the option of reinstalling. But before you do that, boot up with your rescue disk and take a complete backup of the filesystem. Then when you reinstall, skip the formatting and use the existing partitions. Better yet, try to (major) upgrade to a newer version of the same distribution - this should preserve most of your config settings.

Then test everything and copy back any overwritten configs from your backup.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I guess I have no other option, the problem I don't have access to the server only through ssh, and customer support won't help. the only option they have to reinstall from the start, but likely won't keep the data or configs. I think linux distros should include restore points by default.